# How to mix pieces and user selection in order to have exactly 5 elements?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I need to make a widget that lets user select some featured events.
I can do that with a custom widget and an Array Field.
My need is that if the user select less than 5 items I want to fill missing elements with latest event (minus user selection). How can I do this?

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a valid and specific question about apostrophecms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`self.load` method](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/modules/apostrophe-widgets/#load-req-widgets-callback) in `apostrophe-widgets`. You can use the doc manager API there to get piece information and update the widgets as they'll be loaded.

Here's a general example in a widget's index.js file:

```
  construct: function (self, options) {
    self.load = function(req, widgets, callback) {
      var cursor = self.apos.docs.getManager('piece-name').find(req, {
        // Specify the pieces you want
      }, {
        // Fields you want in MongoDB filter style
      }).sort({
        publishedAt: -1
      });

      cursor.toArray(function(err, pieces) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err)
        }
        _.each(widgets, function(widget) {
          // Load up the widget here.
        });
        return callback(null);
      });
    }
  }
```

You'd need to decide whether you want to check the number the editor included before or after making this request.